# Groupby values of dataframe of columns into JSON

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

| class_id | class | code | id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8 | XYZ | A | 1 |
| 8 | XYZ | B | 2 |
| 9 | ABC | C | 3 |

I have a dataframe like above. I want to transform it so the 'codes' column below collects all the unique (code, id) pairs into a JSON format that a class contains.

| class_id | class | codes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 8 | XYZ | [{'code: 'A', 'id': 1}, {'code': 'B', 'id': 2}] |
| 9 | ABC | [{'code: 'C', 'id': 3}] |

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `groupby.apply` where you pass in a lambda that uses the `to_dict` method:

```
out = df.groupby(['class_id','class'])[['code','id']].apply(lambda x: x.to_dict('records')).reset_index(name='codes')
```

Output:

```
   class_id class                                             codes
0         8   XYZ  [{'code': 'A', 'id': 1}, {'code': 'B', 'id': 2}]
1         9   ABC                          [{'code': 'C', 'id': 3}]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers. What would be the best way to rename 'code' and 'id' inside the JSON to something else. So something like {'C': 'B', 'I': 2}

Comment: @hedebyhedge you could rename columns, then use `groupby.apply`